# How to set Delay on GSM shield?

Tags: gsm

I bought a [Gsm module](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/GPRS_Shield_V1.0) recently(not official arduino shield) and i connect it to Arduino uno. The problem (I guess) is , i can't set delay properly, the terminal send it too fast that i missed it or too slow even i set its baud rate to 4800 (I have tried it with many baud from 4800-to-115200).

I uploaded the code to Git ,with [this address](https://github.com/zigi1/Test/blob/master/gsm.c).

More details: For example when i enter `d` in terminal it act like this message came up : `+CMTI: "SM",3` and it want to save it but it miss plus at first of it and it save `CMTI: "SM",3`,

After that it perform this : `AT+CMGR=3` the terminal show the message in half size : `+CMGR: "REC UNREAD","+9*********2","H/E.3D/1","16/02/28,00:27:02+14"` which totally missed body part.

The weird thing is when i put some println on the program it miss more characters , and second weird thing is it missed more character in second run or i push d again.

I have tried to change the delays but no success.How can i fix it ? any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**:

If i make it simpler, when i use these code i get half message :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial serialGPRS(7, 8);
void setup()
{  
  Serial.begin(19200);          
  serialGPRS.begin(19200);              
}
void loop()
{
  serialGPRS.println("AT+CMGR=1");
  delay(1000);
  while(serialGPRS.available()!=0)
    Serial.write(serialGPRS.read());
}
```

like: `+CMGR: "REC READ","+9*******",".H/E.3D/1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SoftwareSerial` receive buffer is getting filled up and discarding characters. You are not reading fast enough from the buffer. Adding `Serial.println()` will slow down your `read`ing even more. The simplest solution to this is to increase the size of the `SoftwareSerial` buffer from its default size of 64 bytes to 256 bytes (or smaller, depending on what works for you).

On a Windows PC, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\libraries\SoftwareSerial`. Open `SoftwareSerial.h` and change the line:

```
#define _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF 64 // RX buffer size
```

to

```
#define _SS_MAX_RX_BUFF 256 // RX buffer size
```

Save the file and try your sketch again.

Comment: It took so long so i changed the code, And there is no way i can test it ,but thank you.(I cant test it but i click it as accept).